# What font is the one used in \documentclass{scrbook}?

Tags: fonts, titles, scrbook

I want to use the font that by deffinition appears in sections titles and etc, when using `\documentclass{scrbook}`, this font,

[image]

Because I want to use this font in the titles but using `\documentclass{article}`. I don't know if I can change the font for the title only, but in this case I need to know the fontname of this particular font.

What I want is to use the font of the titles in `\documentclass{scrbook}` but in the titles of `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the default Sans Serif font, i.e., [Computer Modern Sans](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernsansserif/) for latex and pdflatex, and the very similar [Latin Modern Sans](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/latinmodernsans/) for lualatex and xelatex.

You can get this in most documents just by using `\textsf{...}` or `\sffamily` and document wide with `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.

If you just want it in section, subsection, etc., titles, one quick way for the `article` class would just be: `\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}` (the `bf` is for bold; leave that out if you don't want them bold).

If you also want it in the title/author/date produced by `\maketitle` you could either use `{\sffamily \maketitle}`
or customize things with the [titling](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling?lang=en) package.

Answer (score 2):

another common and widely available font that will give you a similar look, but a little more rounded and with a balanced M, is "arial rounded mt bold":

[image]